# IOS 11+ Location Services Authorization fails even though keys exist

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I get location services to work on iPhone with IOS 12 installed and the target build set to 11?  I am working on a prototype since I remember location services being a bit of a hassle.  I have the following code:

```
-(id) init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [manager setDelegate:self];
    [manager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [manager setDistanceFilter:50];
    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            [self presentAlertForLocationServices];
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"Location restricted");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"Location Denied");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            [manager startUpdatingLocation];
            NSLog(@"Updating locations...");
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
            [manager startUpdatingLocation];
            NSLog(@"Updating locations...");
            break;
    }
}
return self;
```

I have the following keys:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) always uses location </string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs location in order to find nearby points of interest</string>
```

However, I get the following error when running the application:`This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data`.

I have tried the 3 different keys (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysInUseUsageDescription) in various combinations along with the 2 different authorization requests with no luck.  I'm using XCode 10.0 (10A255).  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I did find that Apple had an issue with keys not working properly, but it was over a year ago and I am sure the matter was resolved although I do not know the answer for it.

Comment: Do you have multiple plist files in your project? Which one are you editing?

Comment: There are actually 3 plist files.  One in the main directory, one in the Tests directory, and one in the UITests directory.  I was unintentionally editing the one in the Tests directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure you've edited the correct Info.plist - the one truly used by your app.  Is it the one pointed to in your build settings for that app target?

Comment: Turns out I was editing the Info.plist that belongs to the tests.  If it was a snake it would have bit me.  Thanks